# Which functions $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ are 'totally compatible'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers

> **Definition 0.** For each integer $k$ and each function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, lets define that *$f$ is $k$-compatible* iff there exists a function $g : \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$f(j)+k\mathbb{Z} = g(j+k\mathbb{Z}).$$

For example, every function $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is $0$-compatible (take $g=f$) and $1$-compatible (take $g=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}}$).

> **Definition 1.** Call a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ *totally compatible* iff for all integers $k$, the function $f$ is $k$-compatible.

For example, every univariate polynomial with integer coefficients defines a totally compatible function $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. There's probably other examples, but I can't think of any.

> **Question.** Is there a nice characterization of the totally compatible functions $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Equivalently: let $\pi_k\colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$ be the natural quotient map. Then $f$ is $k$-compatible if and only if there exists $g\colon \Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$ such that $g\circ\pi_k = \pi_k\circ f$. Equivalently: the function $\pi_k\circ f \circ\pi_k^{-1}$ is well-defined (doesn't depend on the choice of preimage under $\pi_k^{-1}$).

Comment: I doubt there is a nice characterization, because you can build totally compatible functions inductively: given its values on any finite interval $\{a,a+1,\dots,b-1,b\}$, the possible values for $f(a-1)$ or $f(b+1)$ can lie in an entire arithmetic progression modulo the least common multiple of all positive integers up to $b-a$. In particular there are uncountably many such functions.